# How to extract/ generate the coordinates of intersection points of a line intersecting an area (in fme-workbench)

Tags: geometry, mesh, intersection, fme

I have a question concerning the FME workbench. I would like to know how I can extract the coordinates of the intersection-points of a line intersecting an area (a mesh with poligons). The coordinates of the intersection-points should have a maximal precision.

To give you some more information about my problem I have attached some screenshots.

[Here you can see the nodes in FME that create the lines. Each line is perpendicular to the mesh. The mesh is hollow inside, so the lines intersect the mesh twice. I would need the intersection coordinates from the first time the line intersects with the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ght6J.png)

[Here you can see the intersections of the lines with the mesh better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvWm8.png)

I would be very thankful, if you could provide any information on how to solve this problem. If you need any more infos, just let me know

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use the FME transformer intersector.  intersected lines will have attributes from polygon. And you can generate points at the ends(line).
and you can segregate the points based on the attribute of a polygon.